# How to highlight original work in a talk where it is not expected?

Tags: citations, presentation

I am a student who is giving a talk on a topic in a few weeks. The talk will be a brief introduction to the topic concerned followed by a rapid survey of recent research and developments.

I have obtained an interesting result in the field by myself which complements a result that I will be talking about, so I am planning to include my result in my talk. However my result has not yet been submitted to any journal and has not been put up online independently.

How should I present this result in my talk? The talk is going to be a competition and being able to present such an independent result (even if it is minor) is considered commendable.
I want to make sure the audience notices that I have found this result. I will definitely be saying it out loud and clear, but I also want to display this somehow in my presentation.

What should be the proper way of such a display? That is, how should I put my name before this result? Shall I write, “Carter, 2017”? But note the work is unpublished. I don’t know if this is reserved only for works that have been published.

Comment: "The talk is going to be a competition..." I feel that this deserves more emphasis and explanation, as a talk is usually *not* a competition (though there may be some competitive undertones).  This makes me think that normal conventions on what to do in a talk may not apply in this context.  Also, this is a good question to ask your advisor, who is presumably much more familiar with your specific situation than we are.

Comment: No no, you see it is just that around 7 students are going to give talks on different topics, and finally a prize will be given to the best talk.

Answer (score 5):

First, make sure that you are referencing the works of others that you build upon. This way, the audience should be able to easily distinguish the results that belong to you vs. the results that belong to others.

For a published work of yours, I'd prefer a **Carter, 2017** citation, including the name of the journal or a conference, and some of the following: name of the article, DOI, link or issue and page number.

For an unpublished work of yours, I'd use an **own work** or **own data** notice. This way, you do not make a false impression that this work is already published. Your audience will possibly infer that these data are fresh from the lab bench. If I were to attend your talk, I'd pay more attention to these data, because these are ones I wouldn't be able to found in the literature (yet).

For an unpublished joint work, still use an **own work** notice, but add **in collaboration with X, University of Y** to give credit both to you and the other person.

Comment: Suppose I an another person have together found a result which I would like to state. Suppose that too is fresh from the bench. Should I write "Joint observation with X" if that person is X?

Comment: @LandonCarter thanks for a reminder, addressed this in the answer.

Comment: Why not "Carter et al., in preparation"?

Comment: @E.P. this will definitely work. Just make sure the first author will not change in the process of publication.